# Are include statments that are within if statements compiled by the server?

Tags: php, if-statement, include, compiler-optimization, page-load-time

I am attempting to reduce load time on my `index.php`.
Will having my `if {code}` statements reduced to `if {include}` decrease load time or are all includes compiled anyway?

i.e.

```
//old code:
<?php
if (isset($_get("about")){
    my_sql code...;
    echo about me code...;
?>

//new code:
<?php
if (isset($_get("about")){
    include "./include/about.php";
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP behavior of include/require inside conditional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906627/php-behavior-of-include-require-inside-conditional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The include will only be included if the `if` condition is `true`. Whether this actually speeds up *compilation* is questionable IMO, since opening and reading another file will probably pretty much negate any speed gained through having to compile less code. You should only separate your code into separate files if it makes the code easier to read and more maintainable. For speed, use an opcode cache.

Comment: ah but i have 4 or 5 (exclusive) `if/else if(isset(%"page"))`s what i was thinking wont it be faster top access two files that are a few hundred (or less) kelobytes each rather than one multi-megabyte file i.e. i have an index.php that displays the whole site, and through ifs selects content so if someone goes to hhaddow.co.uk/?link=show they get my links page (and they shouldn't be able to abuse the `$_get` as i avoid useing anything but `isset` with it)

Comment: Well that clearly falls into the *separate for readability* category. A multi-MB PHP file seems pretty excessive. O_o

Comment: that was a miscount was using the end result size (there are a lot of for in my sql/php code) but index.php without includes is 500 kb to 1 mb and using `if {include}` it goes down to 200-500kb as i have it set to all go through index.php i.e. my about page is mydomain.co.uk/?about=show and there is a line in my code that is `if (isset ($get[about])) {include "./include/about.php"}` and there are 5 or 6 'pages' like this. what i was asking was more to do with the server side compiler