# If an include() is conditional, will PHP include the file even if the condition is not met?

Tags: php

This has been on my mind for quite some time and I figured I should seek an answer from experts.
I want to know if it is a poor programming technique to funnel all PHP requests through a single file. I have been working on a website and not sure if it will scale with growth because I am not 100% certain of how PHP handles the `include()` function.

To better explain how I have build my quasi framework here is a snippet of my root `.htaccess` file:

```
# > Standard Settings
RewriteEngine On

# Ignore all media requests
RewriteRule ^media/ - [L]

# Funnel all requests into model
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _model.php [QSA]
```

So everything except content within the media directory is passed into this single script.

Inside `_model.php` I have all my input sanitisation, user authentication, session data gets pulled from the database, any global variables (commonly used variables like $longTime, $longIP etc...) are set. Requests are routed via interpreting the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` variable.

Essentially I have a `switch()` statement which chooses which module to `include()`. What I don't understand is: when PHP executes, will it execute every single `include()` regardless of whether or not the case directive is true?

I am concerned that after time I will have a lot of these modules - and if PHP does at runtime include all the modules it will end up occupying too much processing power and RAM...

--

Edit:
I am really just asking if PHP will 'read' all those files that it potentially might have to include. I know that it shouldn't actually execute the code.
If one of my `include()` is a 2GB file which takes a long time to process, will PHP always read over that file before executing?

--
Edit:
I have found another similar question (I did search a lot before posting this one)
[PHP behavior of include/require inside conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906627/php-behavior-of-include-require-inside-conditional)

I think I can close this off.

Comment: NO, you have some errors in your code.

Comment: @Akam my code works fine - I am not asking about errors in the code. Just wondering if PHP will read all of the potential included files before executing.

Comment: i think no, must not be

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP behavior of include/require inside conditional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906627/php-behavior-of-include-require-inside-conditional)

Comment: There must be an error, don't you forget the break statements in your case directives ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, PHP will execute include in the moment the code fragment is reached.

This is quite important, because you can have php include file with code directly. E.g.

File1:

```
<?php echo "Foo"; ?>
```

File2:

```
<?php
  echo "Before";
  include("File1");
  echo "After";
?>
```

Sometimes your PHP processor won't even know at compiletime which file to include. Imagine something like `include("File".mt_rand(1,10));`. PHP won't know the filename to include up to the very moment it reaches the include statement.

Comment: This is a very good point. So my method and structuring is not flawed in that sense!

Answer (score 2):

> will PHP include the file even if the condition is not met?

No, `include` and `require` statements are interpreted and evaluated in the same way as other PHP statements. PHP does not scan the script for includes prior to executing.

This can be verified with a simple test:

```
if(false)
{
    include('does_not_exist.php');
}
```

The above produces no error or warnings. If the include was read before execution, you would see a warning like:

> Warning: include(does_not_exist.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ...
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'does_not_exist.php' for inclusion ...

Comment: Yes I knew this was the case (that broken files don't get included - I have been caught up with this in my website with modules being incorrectly linked), but I thought that perhaps PHP did something neat to try and speed up execution by attempting to load things into memory... I guess not!

Comment: Thanks! I thought that is was like C where it's evaluated before execution. Thank you. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @MrCode - I accepted the other answer because his was posted first. Both contributions were very helpful.