# PHP7 const defined within a require (external file) within a conditional (if) is working - why?

Tags: php, if-statement, constants, include, require

While debugging a large body of code, I came across the following that was completely unrelated to my debugging.  I did spend an inordinate amount of time Google searching for a plausible explanation:

The declaration of a `const`, within a `function`, within a conditional (`if`), within a `require` of an external file included.
NOTE:  this was NOT defined as part of a class construct!!

Since this `const` is defined within the context of a conditional, making it run-time? vs compile/parse-time, this should (IMHO) have given an error, but not only was there no error, but the code has been running perfectly in production for over three years!

Would love to hear expert explanations, or even a clue to what I am obviously missing!

**Q1**. Why is constant _DEFITEM not giving an error?

**Q2**. Why is constant _DEFITEM working even though it was not defined using `define`?

Thank you, in advance, and especially to JS, and for the wonderful work this community has done over the last decade!

**REFERENCE**:

[PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

[If an include() is conditional, will PHP include the file even if the condition is not met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727116/if-an-include-is-conditional-will-php-include-the-file-even-if-the-condition)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143439/conditionally-include-files-in-functions-php

**CODE**: Simple stub with a function that gets called, checks a passed-by-value parameter for "SAVE", conditionally including the (ALWAYS available) save module file, and then calling its main function. The included (require) save module file has the const declaration at the top.

> Contrived, but accurate code representation below!  Ellipses represent other code

```
//  main_stub3.php     php file processing client request (included within a main page/script)
<?php
function list_view_save_proc_stub3 (fn_param1, fn_param2...)  {
...
if ("VIEW" === fn_param2)  {
   ...
}
else
if ("SAVE" === fn_param2)  {
   ...
   require _INC . proj_save_module_file.php;           //  _INC is a global constant (path)
   sv_mod_fn ();
}
else
   ...
}  //  END fn list_view_save_proc_stub3
//  END main_stub3.php


//  proj_save_module_file.inc   include file that contains a const declaration and a function
const _DEFITEM = [ 'it_id' => 0, 'it_name' => '', ... ];   //  about ~50 items in array

function sv_mod_fn ()  {
//  some std error checking, building of a row, db connectivity and insertion +
//  message output to client
...
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear what's confusing you, and how all the discussion about includes and conditionals fits together, but a better manual page for `define` and `const` syntax is here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php

Comment: It doesn't appear to be within an conditional statement and it really doesn't matter where/when it gets define. As long as it hasn't already been declared it will work. I'm not seeing anything confusing about it at all really.

Comment: @IMSoP - I did look at all the manuals.  In particular your link specifical points to: ```Note:

As opposed to defining constants using define(), constants defined using the const keyword must be declared at the top-level scope because they are defined at compile-time. This means that they cannot be declared inside functions, loops, if statements or try/ catch blocks.```

Comment: @Dave - My issue (maybe due to an incorrect preconception) is that at compile time the external file is NOT included, but only at run-time, which suggests that at run-time I would  normally get a constant declaration error.

Comment: Ah, I think I see where you're confused now, I'll try to put together an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People often talk about PHP as a "scripting" or even "interpreted" language, but like most modern languages it does have distinct **compilation** and **execution** steps. A lot of the details aren't often relevant, but are crucial to your misunderstanding here.

PHP compiles files when they are first needed; it can also (via [the OpCache extension](https://php.net/opcache)) cache the result of this compilation. Importantly, it always compiles **a single file at a time**, regardless of how that file is used. So everything that happens at compile-time is based on what can be known just looking at that single file.

Once a file is compiled, it can be executed any number of times (either within the same request, or later by getting it from OpCache memory). So everything that happens at execution-time can know everything about the current context it's running in.

To understand your code, you then only need to know two things:

- `const` is evaluated at compile-time
- `require` is evaluated at execution-time

What the manual means when it says `const` can't be used in a conditional is that when a file is compiled, the definition becomes part of the compiled code, unconditionally. Every program that file is part of will include that constant definition. This is different from `define`, which is compiled a bit like a function call - it becomes a marker saying "when you get to this point in the execution of the program, define this constant".

However, compiling the file doesn't make it part of your program. To actually make it part of your program, you use `require` (or its relatives), *at execution-time*.

Only when the `require` line is executed does that compiled file become part of your running program. It might be compiled just in time to execute, or fetched from OpCache having been compiled hours ago, but either way it is *executed* only when that `require` is actually reached. That `require` can be optional, so you might decide to include a different file depending on the day of the week, or at random, or based on user input.

So as far as PHP's concerned, the `const` definition is *unconditionally compiled* into a unit of code that is *conditionally included in your program*.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I was theorizing, but could not really find any definitive write-up to support it.  Appreciate your effort. Thanks again!