# Multiple PHP includes based on conditional statement

Tags: php, include, php-include

I want to include 2 files based on the following conditional statement

```
<?php 
 if (isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_SESSION['name'] == true) { 
 include 'file_a.php'; 
 }else{ 
 include 'file_b.php';
 }
 ?>
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: this should help
[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906627/php-behavior-of-include-require-inside-conditional)

Comment: If you are getting what you want, then there is nothing wrong with this method, I think.

Comment: You can also use ternary operator to change in single line statment

Comment: Using ternary operation in this case won't be rather good choice. It would make code illegible

Answer (score 1):

You can try next code:

```
if(session_id() == '') {
   session_start();
   include !empty($_SESSION['name']) ? 'file_a.php' : 'file_b.php';
}
```

Comment: I don't know why these conditional satements aren't following the logic. I used mysql num rows  to compare and call the include files seperately. Howeve I shall get it working. Thannks,

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by 'correct':

If you mean 'is it valid' then yes, your code will work and there are no syntax errors.

If you mean 'can it be prettier', then perhaps it could, but it's personal preference whether you'd want to use [ternary operators](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) or not:

```
$toShow = isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_SESSION['name'] ? "file_a.php" : "file_b.php";
include $toShow;
```

Again, whether or not this is better or worse than your previous code, is down to your personal opinion.

TL;DR: Yes, your code is correct.